# Difference between var=fun() and var=fun

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know the assigning to variable more specifically. My code:

```
def fun():
    return 5
var=fun()
print(var)
var=fun
print(var)
```

Is there any difference in the both or are they the same? I use Python 3.

Comment: They are different, `var = func()` is *calling* the function, `var = func` is a reference to `func`

Comment: Running your own 6-line code gives you the answer: they are different. So why do you ask us?

Comment: @Julien I didn't want the output of the code, I wanted the difference. However, I ran the code before I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the parenthesis `fun()` would call/run the function, and return `5`, whereas if you don't add the parenthesis `fun`, it wouldn't run the function, it would just give:

```
<function fun at 0x000000D4B44E8730>
```

Whereas with the parenthesis, it would give:

```
5
```

Without calling the function (without using the parenthesis) would just give a function reference, and wouldn't run the function. Whereas if you add the parenthesis it would.

Here is an example:

```
def fun():
    return 'The function is called!'
print(fun())
print(fun)
```

Output:

```
The function is called!
<function fun at 0x0000001615DD7730>
```

Answer (score 3):

`var = fun()` calls the function `fun`. The returned value (in this case, 5) is then assigned to `var`.

`var = fun` assigns the function `fun` refers to, to `var`. You can now call the function by doing either `fun()` or `var()`. Two different names for the same function.

This is what people mean when they say python has 'first-class functions' - they can be treated like any other variable, as opposed to the special treatment they get in languages like Java.